# Plotly treemap : add interaction on cell

Tags: pdf, plotly, treemap, interaction

I am working with plotly treemap to make visualisations on hierarchical data.
I would like to add specific interaction: when clicking on the last level cell, I would like to open a pdf in another tab (working on jupyter notebook, through chrome).

Do you think it is possible ?

For example, if considering this following treemap:
[image: Treemap example]

I would like to open a specific pdf when clicking on IND cell, another pdf when clicking on JPN cell etc.

Comment: maybe with dash?